# Find the pf of Y and the moment generating function of Y

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Toss a coin that lands on heads with probably $\left(\frac1{3}\right)$ until you observe both sides. Let Y be the number of tosses. Find the pf and moment generating function of Y.**

This problem has been hard for me to get started because I'm unsure of how to reason it in the first place. I have tried taking one direction, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

*What I have tried so far:*

For the pf, I figured there are two outcomes. There is one case if it lands on heads first, and one case if it lands on tails first.

If the coin lands on tails first, then I let Y = # of tosses until a head appears. Clearly, Y~$Geo\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$.

So then, for example, we get $P(Y=2) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$, $P(Y=3) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$, $P(Y=2) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$, and so on.

So in general, we get $p(y)$ = $P(Y=y)$ = $(1-p)^{y-1}p$ = $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{y-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ for y = $2, 3, 4, ...$

Similarly, if the coin lands on heads first, I let Y = # of tosses until a tails appears.

Following the same procedure, I get $p(y)$ = $P(Y=y)$ = $(1-p)^{y-1}p$ = $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{y-1}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$ for y = $2, 3, 4...$

One related question I did have was, can I essentially combine both of those properties into one probability function and say:

$p(y)$ = $P(Y=y) = (1-p)^{y-1}p$ = $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{y-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{y-1}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$ for y = $2, 3, 4...$

Or does that not make sense?

For the moment generating function, I started by definition. I decided to try using the combined formula, though I'm unsure if I am able to.

$m_Y(t) = E(e^{ty}) = \sum_{y=2}^\infty e^{ty}p(y) = \sum_{y=2}^\infty e^{ty}[
\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{y-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{y-1}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)]$

At this point I am stuck. I don't know if I'm going in the right direction, or if I should break up those probability functions, or do something else entirely. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have already solved the problem, in order to get an explicit moment-generating function it is enough to compute geometric series of the form $\sum_{y\geq 2} K^y = \frac{K^2}{1-K}$.